# How to know how long user spend on a web site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ip

I made a simple website using html and php.

How to save to a separate file:
IP address of user that came to the website
Time each user spent on the website

Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to use Cookies in PHP that unique user just has a unique cookie, not Ip.